# How to use order by for discounted prices

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have two columns in my database table products.

```
price   discountpercent    
100     10    
200     70
```

My Query

```
 SELECT * FROM products order by ?
```

How can i order by discounted price ?

Comment: `SELECT *, price*(100-discountpercent)/100 AS discountedprice FROM products ORDER BY discountedprice`? I suppose, you want to retrieve the discounted price as well.

Comment: you can order by arbitrary expressions. `order by (price * discountpercent / 100)`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
ORDER BY price * (100 - discountpercent) / 100
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4cf73/1)